# Can the R "for" loop be used in an object name and an excel document name at the same time?

Tags: r, excel

This is my first attempt at a loop in R and I don't know if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do, but if so, I think this would be useful to many people who might find your answer to my question in a Google search.

I'm trying to append 89 Excel spreadsheets together. These spreadsheets have dozens of sheets, and I need to select the one I want as well as delete the first three rows. I know how to do all of this one document at a time, but with 89 documents, boy wouldn't it would be nice to automate this.

One thing that helps is that each document name ends in a date. In my example each document is one day's electricity price data. Because of the date being in the document's name I was hoping to use the first_date:last_date construction.

Here's the example of the coding for a single document upload:

```
library(readxl)
MDFD_20170207 <- read_excel("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_20170207.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "Bilateral Indexes", col_names = FALSE, 
                            skip = 3)
```

And here was my attempt to apply basic R "for" looping material that [I've read](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/) to this case:

```
for (i in 20170207:20170210){
  print(paste(,i<- read_excel("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_,i.xlsx", 
                              sheet = "Bilateral Indexes", col_names = FALSE, 
                              skip = 3)
  ))
}
```

It didn't work, I got the following error message:

```
Error in paste(, i <- read_excel("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_,i.xlsx",  : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

I'm not sure what that means. For example, what argument is it saying is missing?

I hope I've written this with enough explanation so that if a workable answer is given, other people will be able to save time at work not having to upload one document at a time when appending big data sets.

**Update:** Here's another approach I've been working on:

```
    df <- data.frame()
    full_path <- "O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/"
    docs <- c(20170207:20170209)
    for (f in docs){ 
      filename <- paste0(full_path, f,".xlsx")
      tmp_df <- read_excel(filename, sheetName = "Bilateral Indexes", col_names = FALSE, skip = 3)
      df <- rbind(df,tmp_df)
}
```

This all appears to work, in terms of structure, but then it's not accepting my read_excel command:

```
Error in sheets_fun(path) : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/20170207.xlsx' cannot be opened.
```

Comment: When you write `paste(,` and put nothing between the open-paren and the comma, the R interpreter chokes (and gives you an informative error message). The error has nothing to do with the `for`-command, and everything to do with R syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the commas one at a time. I had placed the I after a comma, because that's how that R blog that I linked in my question did it, but clearly that was a mistake because they weren't doing anything like this. Without the commas, R does not give me an error for just having the i as an object name, but it doesn't like the i in the Excel document name. At least that's my interpretation of this error:

Error in sheets_fun(path) : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_i.xlsx' cannot be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the file name string first and then use that variable in your `read_excel` call. I'm assuming you want to append all files' data into one table and that each file has the same structure (namely column names)...

```
#create data frame to store rows for all Excel files
all.rows <- data.frame()

#loop through files and append data to said data frame     
for (i in 20170207:20170210){
    filename = paste("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Prices/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_",i,".xlsx",sep='')
    tmp_table <- read_excel(filename,sheet = "Bilateral Indexes", col_names = FALSE, skip = 3))
    #subset tmp_table to desired columns
    all.rows <- rbind(all.rows, tmp_table[,c('peak prices','off-peak prices')])
}

#now you can perform calculations on the data frame [replace <column> with your column name]
mean.var <- mean(all.rows$<column>)
```

Comment: Thank you, it accepted that command. I see that it didn't create any objects. From my limited understanding of creating loops in R, to access what I've just created I use the print(paste(i)) command right? When I do so it just gives me: [1] "20170210"

Comment: What do you want to do with the Excel data?

Comment: These are daily wholesale electricity prices in the Mid Columbia grid. I want from it two columns: peak prices and off-peak prices to compare with BPA prices.

Answer (score 0):

When saving iterations of an object I prefer to use a list to keep your environment clean. You simply need to subset with double brackets `[[` instead of `[`. Also, make use of the `paste0` function which combines strings with no space.

```
docs <- c(20170207:20170210)
# initialize a list object to save them to
MDFD <- vector("list", length(docs)) # alternatively you could just write <- list()

# way of combining the string
paste0("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Price/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_", docs[1],".xlsx")

for(i in 1:length(docs)){
  # double check that "/P~Port" bit you have there...
  # and you have fixed the date 20170615 too?
  MDFD[[i]] <- read_excel(paste0("O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Price/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_", docs[i],".xlsx"), sheet = "Bilateral Indeces", col_names = FALSE, skip = 3)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Should you want to call the names of each workbook better from the list you might want to do `names(MDFD) <- docs` where you can hit tab after `MDFD$` to select and finish calling which element in the list you would like, such as.

```
MDFD$`20170207`
```

Comment: I checked the path and it's correct. Also, that was sharp of you to notice the date of the folder is more recent, but these older dated files are in there too. 
The first couple lines worked, but that last part, the for command, gives this error: Error in sheets_fun(path) : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'O:/Project/P~Port of Seattle/Price/Mid-C/20170615 Platt's/MDFD_20170207.xlsx' cannot be opened.

Comment: Hm.. is it possible the files are password protected? see https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/84

Comment: I checked, and no they are not password protected. Also, a co-worker suggested that I save them to a local file and I ran it again from the C drive and got the same result. In the R error it's saying "zip file" but these were not downloaded as a zip. Does that have another meaning in R?

Comment: Is the sheet name spelled correctly? `"Bilateral Indeces"` I am convinced the error is simply a "can not find the file" error

Comment: That gives me some hope that we're narrowing it down. The way that I can confirm that it's not the spelling of the sheet is by running the basic command for one file and R has no trouble setting up my data frame with that spelling, one Excel file at a time. If your experience tells you it's an inability to find the file, could the way we've altered the coding of finding the file with this loop language be the cause?

Comment: Can you paste the current code you are trying as an edit to the question? I'll take one more look

Comment: Thank you, I'll post something slightly similar to your edit above in terms of creating an object for document names.

Comment: :) it appears you forgot the `"MDFD_"` in your `full_path` string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that will loop through a set of Excel files in a given directory and load the contents of a specific sheet into an ever-growing dataframe.  This may work better than trying to create every possible file name algorithmically and then handling missing files.

I've added a column to identify the file each row came from and an additional "log dataframe" to track how many rows of data were loaded from each file.

```
library(readxl)

# build an empty data frame to hold all the data
df <- data.frame()

# build an empty dataframe to log the results
log_df <- data.frame()

#your path is different
full_path <- "/home/dale/GetExcelFilesR/files/"

# get a list of all the xlsx files in this folder
file_list <- list.files(path = full_path, pattern = "*.xlsx")

for (f in file_list){
  filename <- paste0(full_path, f)

  #load this file into a temporary dataframe
  tmp_df <- NULL  #make sure it's empty first

  # each sheet had 2 rows at top, 3rd has column names
  tmp_df <- read_excel(filename, sheet = "Specific Sheet Name", col_names = TRUE, skip = 2)

  #add the filename as a column in the data
  tmp_df <- cbind(SourceFile=f, tmp_df)

  #append that temp dataframe to our main dataframe
  df <- rbind(df,tmp_df)

  status_text <- paste0(nrow(tmp_df), " rows read")
  log_df <- rbind(log_df, data.frame(SourceFile=f, Status=status_text))
}

View(log_df)
```